# Interpolate/downscale vector to a given percentage in R

Tags: r, vector

I have a following dummy vector:

```
vctr <- c(601, 629, 652, 688, 653, 633, 625, 622, 653, 667, 605, 595, 667, 653, 
          602, 597, 659, 656, 706, 710, 718, 711, 725, 682, 656, 676, 698, 680, 
          689, 702, 689, 686, 701, 730, 736, 727, 685, 656, 692, 691, 685, 662, 
          678, 695, 720, 718, 694, 701, 713, 724, 685, 665, 664, 702, 680, 685, 
          709, 711, 681, 678, 715, 722, 737, 726, 716, 714, 727, 725, 717, 719, 
          730, 749, 736, 721, 704, 720, 719, 725, 712, 713, 708, 711, 706, 693, 
          682, 693, 701, 702, 699, 696, 693, 688, 695, 694, 687, 687, 699, 707, 
          688, 680, 688, 698, 700, 703, 704, 693, 693, 700, 708, 704, 704, 701, 
          699, 684, 678, 690, 700, 703, 709, 707, 687, 686, 698, 704, 700, 691, 
          686, 686, 699, 717, 709, 697, 694, 688, 676, 676, 689, 701, 720, 721, 
          708, 702, 702, 707, 700, 691, 693, 701, 691, 682, 681, 681, 690, 710, 
          718, 708, 705, 710, 709, 690, 688, 695, 699, 699, 695, 688, 690, 706, 
          712, 707, 706, 704, 701, 694, 679, 694, 690, 695, 690, 700, 699, 709, 
          709, 696, 694, 698, 694, 693, 693, 701, 695, 698, 702, 707, 703, 702, 
          697, 686, 684, 681, 675, 676, 688, 693, 703, 708, 697, 688, 684, 701, 
          697, 702, 696, 704, 696, 690, 688, 680, 686, 702, 714, 696, 687, 692, 
          697, 690, 690, 688, 701, 693, 687, 668, 669, 675, 684, 693, 693, 697, 
          694, 693, 692, 690, 701, 691, 693, 699, 696, 677, 686, 692, 687, 689, 
          705, 696, 688, 671, 670, 670, 687, 698, 694, 687, 682, 690, 675, 688, 
          703, 705, 682, 673, 679, 684, 695, 689, 691, 662, 662, 664, 688, 677, 
          678, 676, 692, 690, 689, 681, 684, 666, 662, 659, 665, 666, 676, 665, 
          660, 667, 695, 708, 696, 670, 664, 670, 674, 668, 666, 663, 658, 658, 
          658, 665, 672, 684, 686, 691, 683, 680, 679, 684, 679, 677, 677, 679, 
          685, 685, 679, 655, 650, 659, 665, 653, 651, 665, 669, 644, 600, 567, 
          549, 551, 549, 543, 541, 566, 576, 564, 546, 546, 534, 537, 530, 534, 
          535, 538, 549, 554, 529, 543, 623, 644, 601, 562, 553, 521, 510, 517, 
          515, 509, 519, 556, 613, 594, 565, 533, 541, 553, 548, 601, 607, 605, 
          564, 584, 633, 693, 711, 711, 725, 729, 720, 739, 734, 708, 703, 709, 
          717, 728, 726, 728, 720, 721, 700, 703, 714, 733, 727, 718, 746, 764, 
          773, 756, 737, 725, 724, 733, 718, 703, 707, 729, 729, 715, 720, 714, 
          703, 693, 701, 693, 688, 681, 694, 707, 702, 701, 709, 720, 713, 705, 
          694, 683, 690, 696, 693, 701, 717, 724, 706, 700, 702, 712, 709, 700, 
          694, 690, 688, 677, 682, 691, 698, 692, 702, 716, 711, 708, 709, 700, 
          702, 715, 715, 695, 690, 696, 705, 702, 688, 689, 696, 704, 703, 715, 
          710, 706, 699, 704, 704, 702, 701, 700, 696, 692, 691, 699, 711, 714, 
          700, 710, 715, 712, 707, 715, 717, 724, 723, 709)
```

I would like to downsize (interpolate) it, so it would be shorter, but it will retain its properties (shape, scale etc.). To be more specific (non-native here, sorry) I would like to perform operation similar to rescaling/converting image between various formats/compression levels such as .png, .jpeg etc..

I found an approx() function from stats package. Using this I can resize the vector to, for example, 1/5 of its initial length:

```
vctr_lin <- stats::approx(vctr, method = "linear", n=100)
vctr_const <- stats::approx(vctr, method = "constant", n=100)
```

It basically does what I want, but it is slow. I would prefer something faster. Also, if it is possible, I would prefer a solution which would allow to shrink the vector to a given percentage. For instance to obtain an output vector which would be of 80% length of the initial one. It would be helpful for me, as IRL I have a set of vectors, similar to this dummy, but of various length. And I would have them all downscaled to a given percentage.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to `sample` without replacement. The new data should retain overall characteristics of the original data. Check to make sure the properties you are interested in is retained.

```
v2 = sample(x = vctr, size = ceiling(0.8 * length(vctr)))

# Compare original and new data
graphics.off()
plot(1:500, sort(vctr), col = "red")
points(seq(1, 500, length.out = length(v2)), sort(v2), col = "blue")
```

Comment: Nope, this does affect the data structure. I posted plots in my answer below.